# Displaying Album title for image - Foreign Keys

Tags: python, django

I am trying to display the album titles related to my image in my admin interface

```
class Album(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 60)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Tag(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.tag

class Image(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 60, blank = True, null = True)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to = get_upload_file_name)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank = True)
    albums = models.ForeignKey('Album')
    width = models.IntegerField(blank = True, null = True)
    height = models.IntegerField(blank = True, null = True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

How I am getting these album titles is with this method

```
def albums_(self):
    lst = [x[1] for x in self.albums.values_list('albums')]
    return ", ".join(lst)
```

However it is not working correctly. I am not sure how to fix this method. How can I display the album title to the appropriate image?

```
class ImageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ["title"]
    list_display = ["__unicode__", "title", "tags_", "albums_", "created"]
    list_filter = ["tags", "albums"]

admin.site.register(Image, ImageAdmin)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, get rid of albums_().  That method makes little-to-no-sense in its current implementation.  Then change ImageAdmin accordingly:

```
class ImageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ["title"]
    # Don't call albums_().  Aside from the fact that it doesn't do what you want it to do,   
    # The functionality you're looking for is already provided by Django:
    list_display = ["title", "tags_", "albums", "created"] 
    list_filter = ["tags", "albums"]
```

When you create a foreignkey the way you have, there will only be 1 album related to that image.  From the wording in your question, it seems you either meant to put the foreignkey field in Album or you wanted a ManyToMany field

Comment: Sorry if the question was worded is a bad way. I'm glad you understood my context. I'm new to Django and its hard to know what I am asking sorry!

Comment: No explanation or apology necessary.  Everyone has to learn sometime. And I work in a non-english-speaking country, so I understand rather well how it is to not know how to say what you want to say.  It'd be somewhat hypocritical to not at least TRY to make sense out of your question.

Comment: the world needs more people like you

Comment: Dont give me too much credit.  I also have a penchant for being a condescending, petty troll.  you just caught me on a good day.